# Confusion about ThreadPool in C#

Tags: c#, threadpool

I' studying about ThreadPool in C# recently. And I wrote a small function to test it. Just as the code shown below:

```
static void threadTest()
        {
            int totalCnt = 2;
            ManualResetEvent manual = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            {
                int cur = i;
                Console.WriteLine("Before thread:" + cur);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) => {
                    Console.WriteLine("In thread:" + cur);
                    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref totalCnt) == 0) manual.Set();
                });
                Console.WriteLine("End thread:" + cur);
            }
            manual.WaitOne();
        }
```

The output of this code is:

```
Before thread:0
End thread:0
Before thread:1
End thread:1
Before thread:2
End thread:2
Before thread:3
End thread:3
In thread:0
In thread:3
In thread:2
In thread:1
```

"In thread:xx" is printed after all loops are over. But every thread needs a temporary variable "cur" to output this line. However,as far as I know, a temporary variable in one loop will be removed from stack after the loop is over. In this example, thread can still visit "cur" when its loop is over. Can anyone explain this to me. Thanks!!

Comment: The variable is destroyed, but its value lives on in a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: *"a temporary variable in one loop will be removed from stack after the loop is over"* -- Where did you found this information, and how is it applicable in your example?

Comment: It doesn't really end up mattering for different reasons, but stack memory (for local variables and spill slots and home space + argument space for calls) is normally allocated *all at once* when a function is called (with *one* subtraction from `rsp`), and deallocated *all at once* when it returns. The big exception is `stackalloc`, which you didn't use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation about lambdas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)

> Lambdas can refer to outer variables. These are the variables that are in scope in the method that defines the lambda expression, or in scope in the type that contains the lambda expression. **Variables that are captured in this manner are stored for use in the lambda expression even if the variables would otherwise go out of scope and be garbage collected**. An outer variable must be definitely assigned before it can be consumed in a lambda expression.

Emphasis mine.

In effect the lambda expression will be rewritten by the compiler to a class, and any outer variable used in the expression will be added as fields in that class.